# Nesting bowls for shipping

Tags: algorithm, optimization, nested

**Problem statement:**
A company sells bowls of various integer sized diameters (inches) and often customers buy a number of these bowls at once.
The company would like to reduce shipping costs by sending the minimum number of packages for an order of bowls to a given customer by finding an optimal nesting of the bowls.
The company has also decided to restrict the nestings with the following limitations:

- No more than 3 bowls should be nested in one nesting.
- A bowl can be nested inside another if it's smaller but not more than 3 inches smaller than the bowl it's directly nested within.

For example, a customer orders the following bowl sizes:

- One 5" bowl
- One 8" bowl
- Two 11" bowls
- One 12" bowl
- Two 15" bowls

The follow is a possible (and optimal) nesting:
[15] [15,12,11] [11,8,5]

Is there an algorithm to always provide an optimal nesting?

I've looked through many similar questions here on stackoverflow and googled around, but can't find this exact problem, nor am I able to map any similar problems over to this problem space in a way that solves the problem.

This was actually posted in another forum by a real business owner. A number of the developers tried to help, ultimately finding a heuristic solution that provided an optimal solution most of the time but not always.

I can share the chosen algorithm one of the developers put forward as well as a few approaches I tried myself.

I'm just very curious about this problem and if there is an algorithm that can actually do this, or the best solution will be heuristic. If you can either give an idea of how to approach this, share an algorithm, or send a link to a similar problem that can be mapped to this one, that would be awesome.

Comment: It's a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is NP-complete, but greedy approximations are doing well enough for practical purposes

Comment: @Marat That isn't how NP-completeness works. All problems in NP can be mapped to an NP complete problem.  But can you map all instances of an NP-complete problem to this one?

Comment: @btilly let me quote the Wiki: "It is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems shown to be NP-complete in 1972. "

Comment: @Marat You can quote, but do you understand?  There is no known polynomial time algorithm which can solve every set cover problem.  But we only need to solve a restricted type of set cover problems here.  And it is possible to have a polynomial time algorithm to solve the special case.

Comment: @btilly do it then?

Comment: @Marat Have patience.  I am doing it.  This can be solved by a dynamic programming problem and it is polynomial, not pseudopolynomial.

Comment: @Marat See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72850480/585411 for a guaranteed polynomial time solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with dynamic programming in polynomial time.

The idea is that we ONLY care about how many boxes there are total, and how many boxes there are of different top bowl sizes.  We don't care about the details beyond that.  This is a polynomial amount of state, and so we can track through the calculation and enumerate one arrangement per possible state in a polynomial time.  We then reconstruct the minimal packing of bowls into boxes from that arrangement.

```
class Arrangement:
    def __init__(self, next_bowl, prev_arrangement=None):
        self.prev_arrangement = prev_arrangement
        self.add_rule = None
        self.open1 = {}
        self.open2 = {}
        self.next_bowl = next_bowl
        if prev_arrangement is None:
            self.boxes = 0
            for i in range(next_bowl, next_bowl + 4):
                self.open1[i] = 0
                self.open2[i] = 0
        else:
            self.boxes = prev_arrangement.boxes
            for i in range(next_bowl, next_bowl + 4):
                self.open1[i] = prev_arrangement.open1.get(i, 0)
                self.open2[i] = prev_arrangement.open2.get(i, 0)

    # This will be tuples of tuples.
    def state(self):
        open1 = (self.open1[i+self.next_bowl] for i in range(4))
        open2 = (self.open2[i+self.next_bowl] for i in range(4))
        return (open1, open2)

    def next_arrangements(self, bowl):
        base_arrangement = Arrangement(bowl, self)
        base_arrangement.boxes += 1
        base_arrangement.add_rule = ("new",)
        old_count = self.open2.get(bowl, 0)
        base_arrangement.open2[bowl] = old_count + 1
        yield base_arrangement

        for i in range(1, 4):
            if 0 < self.open1.get(bowl+i, 0):
                next_arrangement = Arrangement(bowl, self)
                next_arrangement.open1[bowl+i] -= 1
                next_arrangement.add_rule = ("open", 1, bowl+i)
                yield next_arrangement

            if 0 < self.open2.get(bowl+i, 0):
                next_arrangement = Arrangement(bowl, self)
                next_arrangement.open2[bowl+i] -= 1
                next_arrangement.open1[bowl] += 1
                next_arrangement.add_rule = ("open", 2, bowl+i)
                yield next_arrangement

    def find_boxes(self):
        items = self._find_boxes()
        boxes = items["full"]
        for more_boxes in items["open1"].values():
            boxes.extend(more_boxes)
        for more_boxes in items["open2"].values():
            boxes.extend(more_boxes)

        return list(reversed(sorted(boxes)))


    def _find_boxes(self):
        if self.prev_arrangement is None:
            return {
                "full": [],
                "open1": {},
                "open2": {},
            }
        else:
            items = self.prev_arrangement._find_boxes()
            rule = self.add_rule
            if rule[0] == "new":
                if self.next_bowl not in items["open2"]:
                    items["open2"][self.next_bowl] = [[self.next_bowl]]
                else:
                    items["open2"][self.next_bowl].append([self.next_bowl])
            elif rule[0] == "open":
                if rule[1] == 1:
                    box = items["open1"][rule[2]].pop()
                    box.append(self.next_bowl)
                    items["full"].append(box)
                elif rule[1] == 2:
                    box = items["open2"][rule[2]].pop()
                    box.append(self.next_bowl)
                    if self.next_bowl not in items["open1"]:
                        items["open1"][self.next_bowl] = [box]
                    else:
                        items["open1"][self.next_bowl].append(box)
            return items
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.boxes) + "  open1:" + str(self.open1) + "  open2:" + str(self.open2)

def bowl_nesting (bowls):
    bowls = list(reversed(sorted(bowls))) # Largest to smallest.
    start_arrangement = Arrangement(bowls[0])


    arrange = {start_arrangement.state(): start_arrangement}
    for bowl in bowls:
        next_arrange = {}
        for state, arrangement in arrange.items():
            for next_arrangement in arrangement.next_arrangements(bowl):
                state = next_arrangement.state()
                if state in next_arrange and next_arrange[state].boxes <= next_arrangement.boxes:
                    pass # We are not an improvement.
                else:
                    next_arrange[state] = next_arrangement
        arrange = next_arrange

    min_boxes = len(bowls)
    min_box_list = None
    for arrangement in arrange.values():
        if arrangement.boxes <= min_boxes:
            min_boxes = arrangement.boxes
            min_box_list = arrangement.find_boxes()

    return min_box_list

print(bowl_nesting([15, 15, 12, 11, 11,8,5]))
```

Now while the above solution works, it is inefficient.  Suppose that we have up to `k` bowls of any given size.  The number of combinations of `open1[bowl]` and `open2[bowl]` that allows is `k choose 2 = k*(k-1)/2)`.  When we consider that our state has 4 sizes in it, that's `O(k^8 / 16` possible states.  We do that for the number of bowls to get `O(n k^8)`.  This doesn't scale well.

We can do better by making the following notes:

1. In any arrangement with an `open2[bowls+3]` option, you do not do worse by moving the next bowl out of whatever box you were going to put it in, and putting it there instead.
2. If there is an `open2[bowls+2]` option and an `open2[bowls+1]` option, you never do worse by picking `open2[bowls+2]`.
3. If there is an `open1[bowls+i]` option and an `open1[bowls+j]` option with `1 <= i < j <= 3` then you never do worse picking `open1[bowls+i]` instead.

This optimization means fewer choices, which speeds you up by a constant.  But also you cannot have `open2[bowls+3]` and also have `open2[bowls]`.  So that `O(k^8)` becomes `O(k^7)` states.  And adding to the boxes with larger bowls will reduce how much of the potential state space we actually visit.  This should lead to a better constant.

Here is this logic with a minor refactor to cleanup the code.

```
class Arrangement:
    def __init__(self, next_bowl, prev_arrangement=None, choice=None, position=None):
        self.prev_arrangement = prev_arrangement
        self.add_rule = None
        self.open1 = {}
        self.open2 = {}
        self.next_bowl = next_bowl
        if prev_arrangement is None:
            self.boxes = 0
            for i in range(next_bowl, next_bowl + 4):
                self.open1[i] = 0
                self.open2[i] = 0
        else:
            self.boxes = prev_arrangement.boxes
            for i in range(next_bowl, next_bowl + 4):
                self.open1[i] = prev_arrangement.open1.get(i, 0)
                self.open2[i] = prev_arrangement.open2.get(i, 0)

        if choice is not None:
            self.choice(choice, position)

    # This will be tuples of tuples.
    def state(self):
        open1 = (self.open1[i+self.next_bowl] for i in range(4))
        open2 = (self.open2[i+self.next_bowl] for i in range(4))
        return (open1, open2)

    def choice (self, rule, position=None):
        self.add_rule = (rule, position)
        if rule == "new":
            self.boxes += 1
            self.open2[self.next_bowl] += 1
        elif rule == "open1":
            self.open1[position] -= 1
        elif rule == "open2":
            self.open2[position] -= 1
            self.open1[self.next_bowl] += 1


    def next_arrangements(self, bowl):
        if 0 < self.open2.get(bowl+3, 0):
            yield Arrangement(bowl, self, "open2", bowl+3)
        else:
            yield Arrangement(bowl, self, "new")

            for i in [3, 2, 1]:
                if 0 < self.open1.get(bowl+i, 0):
                    yield Arrangement(bowl, self, "open1", bowl+i)
                    break

            for i in [2, 1]:
                if 0 < self.open2.get(bowl+i, 0):
                    yield Arrangement(bowl, self, "open2", bowl+i)
                    break

    def find_boxes(self):
        items = self._find_boxes()
        boxes = items["full"]
        for more_boxes in items["open1"].values():
            boxes.extend(more_boxes)
        for more_boxes in items["open2"].values():
            boxes.extend(more_boxes)

        return list(reversed(sorted(boxes)))

    def _find_boxes(self):
        if self.prev_arrangement is None:
            return {
                "full": [],
                "open1": {},
                "open2": {},
            }
        else:
            items = self.prev_arrangement._find_boxes()
            rule = self.add_rule
            if rule[0] == "new":
                if self.next_bowl not in items["open2"]:
                    items["open2"][self.next_bowl] = [[self.next_bowl]]
                else:
                    items["open2"][self.next_bowl].append([self.next_bowl])
            elif rule[0] == "open1":
                box = items["open1"][rule[1]].pop()
                box.append(self.next_bowl)
                items["full"].append(box)
            elif rule[0] == "open2":
                box = items["open2"][rule[1]].pop()
                box.append(self.next_bowl)
                if self.next_bowl not in items["open1"]:
                    items["open1"][self.next_bowl] = [box]
                else:
                    items["open1"][self.next_bowl].append(box)
            return items
def bowl_nesting (bowls):
    bowls = list(reversed(sorted(bowls))) # Largest to smallest.
    start_arrangement = Arrangement(bowls[0])


    arrange = {start_arrangement.state(): start_arrangement}
    for bowl in bowls:
        next_arrange = {}
        for state, arrangement in arrange.items():
            for next_arrangement in arrangement.next_arrangements(bowl):
                state = next_arrangement.state()
                if state in next_arrange and next_arrange[state].boxes <= next_arrangement.boxes:
                    pass # We are not an improvement.
                else:
                    next_arrange[next_arrangement.state()] = next_arrangement
        arrange = next_arrange

    min_boxes = len(bowls)
    min_box_list = None
    for arrangement in arrange.values():
        if arrangement.boxes <= min_boxes:
            min_boxes = arrangement.boxes
            min_box_list = arrangement.find_boxes()

    return min_box_list

print(bowl_nesting([15, 15, 12, 11, 11,8,5]))
```

Comment: Good point about there being only three classes of packages, full, open1, open2.

Comment: @btilly - Wow, looks like it works great. So fast too.
Bear with me, I'm not quite on the same level here. Also not knowing Python, I'm translating some of the syntax as I port it over to JS.
In the mean time, could you explain:
1) What you mean by "*how many boxes there are of different top bowl sizes*"
2) The difference between open1 and open2

Comment: @steeveesas `open1` is number of boxes that are open to having 1 more bowl.  (ie they have 2.)  And `open2` is open to having 2 more bowls.  The top bowl is the top bowl in the box - in other words the next one can be that size -1, -2, or -3.

Comment: @steeveesas I added a bug fix and an optimization that is worth considering.

Comment: @steeveesas And, sadly, my optimization had a bug.  Now fixed.  Along with a refactor to make the code easier to read.

Comment: @btilly - Tx for the improvement, it runs way faster (if curious, see my post below to access a spreadsheet to compare them w/ various bowls)...Now just out of curiosity: 1) If this were to be generalized to allow for bowl sizes to be as much as 'd' distance apart (e.g. d = 5" would mean a 5" bowl could be nested inside a 10" bowl) then I guess this would still be linear on n bowls right? The number of sizes in the state would go up to (d+1) and then it would be O(n k^(d+1))? Am I doing that right? Implementing this would be pretty simple - just changing 3 to d in the code pretty much...

Comment: 2) Secondly, if you allowed the number of bowls per box to go up to 'b' bowls would it still be polynomial on n: O(n ( k choose (b -1) )^(d+1))? Again just curious...I would think this generalization would take some doing since now you'd have open3, open4, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can calculate an optimal nesting. As you presented, start with the bowls sorted in reverse order.

```
15,15,12,11,11,8,5
```

Assign the minimum number of starting bowls, corresponding to the count of the largest bowl.

```
[15] [15]
```

As we iterate element by element, the state we need to keep is the smallest bowl size and count in each container per index visited.

```
index 0, [(15, 1), (15, 1)]
```

(The state can be further refined to a multiset of those packages with identical count and smallest bowl size, which would add some complication.)

The choice for any element is which box (or set of boxes with similar state) to add it to or whether to start a new box with it.

```
index 1, [(15, 1), (12, 2)]
or
index 1, [(15, 1), (15, 1), (12, 1)]
```

We can explore these branches in an iterative or recursive breadth first search prioritised by the number of elements remaining plus the number of packages in the state, avoiding previously seen states.

We can further prune the search space by avoiding branches with the same or more count of packages than the best we've already seen.

This approach would amount to brute force in the sense of exploring all relevant branches. But hopefully the significant restrictions of package size and bowl size relationship would narrow the search space considerably.

Comment: Assuming that the bowl sizes are integers, we can compress the state further by censoring the sizes of the bowls more than three inches larger than the smallest open bowl. Then this is a polynomial-time algorithm (albeit with a terrible bound).

Comment: גלעד ברקן - Thanks! I'd like to try implementing this in JS after I implement @btilly 's solution. It would be cool to compare them and add in the efficiencies you and David Eisenstat recommended

Answer (score 0):

**This "Answer" is based on btilly's solution (the accepted answer).**

Thank you @btilly for sticking with this and taking the time to revise the algorithm and fix bugs!

Since this was originally set within the context of Google Apps Script, I've rewritten this in Javascript and want to share the JS code with anyone else that might want it.

btilly's improved algorithm does indeed run much quicker than the first. Though the improvement factor depends on the bowls provided I've noticed it running up to 50 times faster in some of my sample sets.

**Below is the JS code. Some caveats:**

- I've kept the same structure and same naming as much as possible in copying over btilly's solution.
- There's no guarantee I did not introduce bugs while porting over btilly's code.
- I'm not too familiar with many modern/proper JS conventions and also I don't know Python at all, so translating some of the concepts was tough and although I think my code is now bug free, if you spot any bugs, inefficiencies, bad programming ideas, please let me know and I'll update the below code.
- I added a count to the state creation to make each state unique, since in my Apps Script implementation the JS runtime kept stringifying the arrays so that two states were sometimes considered the same even if they were not (e.g. the previous arrangement's bowl was the same size as another arrangement's bowl, but not the same bowl - the way two 10" bowls might appear to a 9" bowl for example). This was not needed in Python since the generators were unique based on their memory addresses. If you know a better way to do this in JS, please let me know. Seems a little sloppy the way I did it.

**Improved/faster code (Javascript):**

```
class Arrangement2{

  constructor(next_bowl, prev_arrangement, choice, position){

    this.prev_arrangement = prev_arrangement;
    this.add_rule = null;
    this.open1 = {};
    this.open2 = {};
    this.next_bowl = next_bowl;
    if (prev_arrangement == null){
      this.boxes = 0;
      for (let i = next_bowl; i < next_bowl + 4; i++){
        this.open1[i] = 0;
        this.open2[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    else{
      this.boxes = prev_arrangement.boxes;
      for (let i = next_bowl; i < next_bowl + 4; i++){
        this.open1[i] = prev_arrangement.open1[i] != null ? prev_arrangement.open1[i] : 0;
        this.open2[i] = prev_arrangement.open2[i] != null ? prev_arrangement.open2[i] : 0;
      }
    }

    if(choice != null){
      this.choice(choice,position);
    }

  }

  state(){
    
    let open1 = {};
    let open2 = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      open1[i+this.next_bowl] = this.open1[i+this.next_bowl];
      open2[i+this.next_bowl] = this.open2[i+this.next_bowl];
    }
    var toReturn = [];

    //Used to make each state unique, without this the algorithm may not always find the best solution
    Arrangement2.count++;

    toReturn.push(Arrangement2.count);
    toReturn.push(open1);
    toReturn.push(open2);

    return toReturn;

  }

  choice(rule, position){
    this.add_rule = [rule, position];
    if( rule == "new" ){
      this.boxes += 1;
      this.open2[this.next_bowl] += 1;
    }
    else if( rule == "open1" ){
      this.open1[position] -= 1;
    }
    else if( rule == "open2" ){
      this.open2[position] -= 1;
      this.open1[this.next_bowl] += 1;
    }
  }

  * next_arrangements (bowl){

    if( 0 < (this.open2[bowl+3] != null ? this.open2[bowl+3] : 0)){
      yield new Arrangement2(bowl, this, "open2", bowl + 3);
    }
    else{
      yield new Arrangement2(bowl, this, "new", null);

      for(let i = 3; i > 0; i--){
        if (this.open1[bowl+i] != null ? this.open1[bowl+i] : 0){
            yield new Arrangement2(bowl, this, "open1", bowl+i);
            break ;
        }
      }         

      for(let i = 2; i > 0; i--){
        if (this.open2[bowl+i] != null ? this.open2[bowl+i] : 0){
            yield new Arrangement2(bowl, this, "open2", bowl+i);
            break ;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  find_boxes(){

    let items = this._find_boxes();
    let boxes = items["full"];
    for (const [key, more_boxes] of Object.entries(items["open1"])) {
      boxes = boxes.concat(more_boxes);
    }
    for (const [key, more_boxes] of Object.entries(items["open2"])) {
      boxes = boxes.concat(more_boxes);
    }

    //Max --> Min (i.e [ 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 7, 7, 7 ])
    boxes.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
    return boxes; //boxes.sort().reverse(); //list(reversed(sorted(boxes)));

  }


  _find_boxes(){
    
    if (this.prev_arrangement == null){

      return {
          "full": [],
          "open1": {},
          "open2": {},
      }

    }
    else{

      let items = this.prev_arrangement._find_boxes();
      let rule = this.add_rule;
      if (rule[0] == "new"){
        if (!(this.next_bowl in items["open2"])){
          items["open2"][this.next_bowl] = [[this.next_bowl]];
        }
        else{
          items["open2"][this.next_bowl].push([this.next_bowl]);
        }
      }
      else if( rule[0] == "open1"){
        let box = items["open1"][rule[1]].pop();
        box.push(this.next_bowl);
        items["full"].push(box);
      }
      else if( rule[0] == "open2"){
        let box = items["open2"][rule[1]].pop();
        box.push(this.next_bowl);
        if (!(this.next_bowl in items["open1"])){
          items["open1"][this.next_bowl] = [box];
        }
        else{
          items["open1"][this.next_bowl].push(box);
        }
      }

      return items;

    }
  }

  __str__(){
    return this.next_bowl + " " + JSON.stringify(this.boxes) + "  open1:" + JSON.stringify(this.open1) + "  open2:" + JSON.stringify(this.open2);
  }

}

allStates_nesting_improved = function (bowls){
    
    //Used to make each state unique, without this the algorithm may not always find the best solution
     Arrangement2.count = 0;
    
    //Max --> Min (i.e [ 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 7, 7, 7 ])
    bowls.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});

    let start_arrangement = new Arrangement2(bowls[0], null);

    let returnObj = start_arrangement.state();
    let arrange = {[returnObj]:start_arrangement};
    
    for (const [key, bowl] of Object.entries(bowls) ) {
      let next_arrange = {};
      for (let [state, arrangement] of Object.entries(arrange) ) {

        let next_arrangements = arrangement.next_arrangements(bowl);
        let next_arrangement = next_arrangements.next();

        while(next_arrangement.value != undefined){

          next_arrangement = next_arrangement.value;
          
          let state = next_arrangement.state();
          let nextArrange_state = next_arrange[state];
          if ( next_arrange[state] != undefined && (nextArrange_state === state) && next_arrange[state].boxes <= next_arrangement.boxes){
              continue ; // # We are not an improvement.
          }
          else{
              next_arrange[next_arrangement.state()] = next_arrangement;
          }
          next_arrangement = next_arrangements.next();
        }

      }

      arrange = next_arrange;

    }

    let min_boxes = bowls.length;
    let min_box_list = null;
    
    for (const [key, arrangement] of Object.entries(arrange) ) {
      if (arrangement.boxes <= min_boxes){
          min_boxes = arrangement.boxes;
          min_box_list = arrangement.find_boxes();
      }
    }

    console.log(min_box_list);
    return min_box_list;

}
```

**Original code (Javascript):**

```
class Arrangement1{

  constructor(next_bowl, prev_arrangement){

    this.prev_arrangement = prev_arrangement;
    this.add_rule = null;
    this.open1 = {};
    this.open2 = {};
    this.next_bowl = next_bowl;
    if (prev_arrangement == null){
      this.boxes = 0;
      for (let i = next_bowl; i < next_bowl + 4; i++){
        this.open1[i] = 0;
        this.open2[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    else{
      this.boxes = prev_arrangement.boxes;
      for (let i = next_bowl; i < next_bowl + 4; i++){
        this.open1[i] = prev_arrangement.open1[i] != null ? prev_arrangement.open1[i] : 0;
        this.open2[i] = prev_arrangement.open2[i] != null ? prev_arrangement.open2[i] : 0;
      }
    }
    
  }

  state(){

    //Used to make each state unique, without this the algorithm may not always find the best solution
    Arrangement1.count++;
    
    let open1 = {};
    let open2 = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      open1[i+this.next_bowl] = this.open1[i+this.next_bowl];
      open2[i+this.next_bowl] = this.open2[i+this.next_bowl];
    }
    var toReturn = [];
    toReturn.push(Arrangement1.count);
    toReturn.push(open1);
    toReturn.push(open2);
    
    return toReturn;
  }

  * next_arrangements (bowl){

    let base_arrangement = new Arrangement1(bowl, this);
    base_arrangement.boxes += 1;
    base_arrangement.add_rule = ["new"];
    let old_count = this.open2[bowl] != null ? this.open2[bowl] : 0;
    base_arrangement.open2[bowl] = old_count + 1;
    yield base_arrangement;

    for(let i = 1; i < 4; i++){
      if (0 < (this.open1[bowl+i] != null ? this.open1[bowl+i] : 0)){
        let next_arrangement = new Arrangement1(bowl, this);
        next_arrangement.open1[bowl+i] -= 1;
        next_arrangement.add_rule = ["open", 1, bowl+i];
        yield next_arrangement;
      }

      if (0 < (this.open2[bowl+i] != null ? this.open2[bowl+i] : 0)){
        let next_arrangement = new Arrangement1(bowl, this);
        next_arrangement.open2[bowl+i] -= 1;
        next_arrangement.open1[bowl] += 1;
        next_arrangement.add_rule = ["open", 2, bowl+i];
        yield next_arrangement;
      }
    }

  }

  find_boxes(){

    let items = this._find_boxes();
    let boxes = items["full"];
    
    for (const [key, more_boxes] of Object.entries(items["open1"])) {
      boxes = boxes.concat(more_boxes);
    }
    for (const [key, more_boxes] of Object.entries(items["open2"])) {
      boxes = boxes.concat(more_boxes);
    }

    //Max --> Min (i.e [ 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 7, 7, 7 ])
    boxes.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
    return boxes;

  }


  _find_boxes(){
    
    if (this.prev_arrangement == null){
      return {
          "full": [],
          "open1": {},
          "open2": {},
      }
    }
    else{
      let items = this.prev_arrangement._find_boxes();
      let rule = this.add_rule;
      if (rule[0] == "new"){
          if (!(this.next_bowl in items["open2"])){
            items["open2"][this.next_bowl] = [[this.next_bowl]];
          }
          else{
            items["open2"][this.next_bowl].push([this.next_bowl]);
          }
      }
      else if( rule[0] == "open"){
        if (rule[1] == 1){
          let box = items["open1"][rule[2]].pop();
          box.push(this.next_bowl);
          items["full"].push(box);
        }
        else if( rule[1] == 2){
          let box = items["open2"][rule[2]].pop();
          box.push(this.next_bowl);
          if (!(this.next_bowl in items["open1"])){
            items["open1"][this.next_bowl] = [box];
          }
          else{
            items["open1"][this.next_bowl].push(box);
          }
        }

      }

      return items;

    }
  }

  __str__(){
    return this.next_bowl + " " + JSON.stringify(this.boxes) + "  open1:" + JSON.stringify(this.open1) + "  open2:" + JSON.stringify(this.open2);
  }

}

allStates_nesting = function (bowls){
    
  //Used to make each state unique, without this the algorithm may not always find the best solution
  Arrangement1.count = 0;
  
  //Max --> Min (i.e [ 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 7, 7, 7 ])
  bowls.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});

  let start_arrangement = new Arrangement1(bowls[0], null);
  let returnObj = start_arrangement.state();
  let arrange = {[returnObj]:start_arrangement};
  
  for (const [key, bowl] of Object.entries(bowls) ) {
    let next_arrange = {};
    for (let [state, arrangement] of Object.entries(arrange) ) {
      let next_arrangements = arrangement.next_arrangements(bowl);
      let next_arrangement = next_arrangements.next();

      while(next_arrangement.value != undefined){

        next_arrangement = next_arrangement.value;
        
        let state = next_arrangement.state();
        let nextArrange_state = next_arrange[state];
        if ( next_arrange[state] != undefined && (nextArrange_state === state) && next_arrange[state].boxes <= next_arrangement.boxes){
            continue ; // # We are not an improvement.
        }
        else{
            next_arrange[state] = next_arrangement;
        }
        next_arrangement = next_arrangements.next();
      }
    }
    arrange = next_arrange;

  }

  let min_boxes = bowls.length;
  let min_box_list = null;
  
  for (const [key, arrangement] of Object.entries(arrange) ) {
    if (arrangement.boxes <= min_boxes){
      min_boxes = arrangement.boxes;
      min_box_list = arrangement.find_boxes();
    }
  }

  return min_box_list;

}
```

**See it in action**

Here is a link to a spreadsheet testbed with 3 algorithms:

1. Algorithm 1: A heuristic algorithm another developer provided (runs fast but doesn't always find the optimal solution and ignores some of the requirements in some of its solutions for simplicity's sake)
2. Algorithm 2: btilly's revised algorithm (faster)
3. Algorithm 3: btilly's first attempt

[Bowl Nesting Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qa7LzwuD9jEHifdgXPip9wIKrmaYoZ49agFH121woG0/edit?usp=sharing)

Feel free to make a copy and modify the code and/or add your own algorithm to compare it with the others. (The orange "Run" button won't work since the spreadsheet is in "Viewer" mode. You'll need to make a copy to run it).

To make a copy go to

- File -> Make a copy.

Once you have your own copy, you can click the "Run" button or go to the code by clicking

- Extensions -> Apps Script

You can then modify and/or add your own algorithm to the mix.
You'll also have to authorize the script to run as with all Apps Script scripts.

*If you're worried about authorizing it, of course check out the code before clicking run to make sure there isn't anything nefarious in there.*